# Visual studio 2010 - Use Local IIS web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I am trying to setup my website on iis 7 and so far I have done the following:

- Installed iis7 and all the main components.
- In iis I have created a new website.
- Through visual studio I have created a new virtual directory.

[image: Virtual directory with files]

[image: virtual directory in visual studio]

I have enabled directory browsing because my problem is I am not sure how routing works with iis. In visual studio development server it goes to the default page without having to specify the specific path.

My only theory is changing my global.asax file but I still am not sure what to do,

[image: Directory]

[image: 404]

[image: Visual studio development server works!]

**Global asax**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace UserManager
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            //routes.IgnoreRoute("/}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    "Default", // Route name
            //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            //);

            routes.MapRoute(
              "Default", // Route name
              "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "UserManager", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
          );

            ///* User Manager routing */
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    "UserManager", // Route name
            //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            //    new { Controller = "UserManager", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //    );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "UserManagerCreateUser", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { Controller = "UserManager", action = "CreateUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
               "UserManagerLookUpGroupName", // Route name
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { Controller = "UserManager", action = "LookUpGroupName", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );

            routes.MapRoute(
               "UserManagershowError", // Route name
               "UserManager/showError/sErrorMessage", // URL with parameters
               new { Controller = "UserManager", action = "showError", UrlParameter.Optional}
               );

            /* User Status routing */
            routes.MapRoute(
                "UserStatus", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { Controller = "UserStatus", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            /* Email Distribution list routing */
            routes.MapRoute(
                "EmailDistributionList", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { Controller = "EmailDistributionList", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            /* Email User Details routing */
            routes.MapRoute(
                "EmailUserDetails", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { Controller = "EmailUserDetails", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Summary**

Trying to setup an MVC 3 intranet site on IIS7. Don't know if the routing requests are wrong because it cant find the page. Screenshots show in visual studio development server how it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to enable directory browsing.

Try adding a New Site in IIS not a virtual directory.  When you create it assign the port to like 9000 then you can access your site with `http://localhost:9000/`

Next, click on Application Pools.  Right click on the new site and go to basic settings.  Make sure the version of the .NET framework is V4 not v2 and the managed pipeline mode is Integrated not Classic.

Also, before you transition over to IIS, make sure the site is running correctly with the Visual Studio Development server.

Comment: @BreetAllred I did you suggestions. Instead of localhost it is my network ip. I changed the site to .net 4.0 through application pool. It originally said the same name as my site which is Test. It also works fine in visual studio in development server mode. Now the error is : HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. Also the site physical path is my documents where the project is.

Comment: It maybe be a permissions issue now.  Try giving IIS_IUSRS permissions to the folder through Windows Explorer.  Right Click on the Folder in windows Explorer -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Add, then enter IIS_IUSRS, then add them.  Depending on what you are doing it may only need Read access.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem with your routing, 
Check that your site is actually using framework 4.0
Check that the managed pipeline is set to integrated
and if your deployment server is different than your developing server then make sure mvc 3.0 is installed in your deployment server

Comment: How do I make sure mvc 3.0 is installed on the server? IIS is also on my work machine.